# How do I properly save and load a Hashmap with keys values of List<String> into a JSON file?

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<List<String>, Integer>` that I'm trying to load from a JSON file and set to a variable in Java, but I'm struggling with this. If I try to cast the object/string from the JSON file, it gives me an unchecked cast error and my application crashes. I've tried many solutions, like loading a hashmap from a string or object, but none of them work. Is there a good way to load a hashmap, where a list is the key, from a JSON file? If loading is not the issue, is there a better way to save the hashmap to JSON?

Here's the example JSON (not hardcoded, it can have stuff added and removed depending on the Hashmap that is saved):

```json
"ImageData":
"{[ProjectName, Time/Date, Long, Lat, Altitude, Address, Code, Note, Direction, NE]=2},
    {[ProjectName, Time/Date, Long, Lat, Altitude, Address, Code, Note, Direction, NE]=1}"
```

Here's how I'm currently saving the hashmap:

```java
dataJson.put("ImageData",application.imageInfo);
```

`application.imageInfo` is the `HashMap<List<String>, Integer>`.

Here's my current attempt at loading the hashmap using Jackson:

```java
HashMap result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json.getString("ImageData").replace("[","").replace("]",""), HashMap.class);
```

Although it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('3' (code 51)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

So how should I load the `HashMap<List<String>, Integer>` from the JSON into a `HashMap` variable?

EDIT (solution):
I found a solution that works pretty well.

```java
String[] parts = hashstr.split(",\"");
for (String part : parts) {
    String[] splithash = part.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("{", "").split("\":");                   
    application.imageInfo.put(Arrays.asList(splithash[0].replace("\"", "").split(",")), Integer.parseInt(splithash[1].replace("}", "")));
    }
```

You can pretty much just take the hashmap string, split it up into each part that a hashmap would have, then add them.

Comment: Is your JSON accurate? It seems to have unnecessary quotes around the main object.

Comment: @AdamWise My apologies, I made a small mistake in the JSON. I have edited it to have the correct JSON.